# Кодировка mysql в командной строке

Tags: mysql

Использую mysql
При выводе в командной строке кракозябры
Подскажите как вывести правильные записи кирилицу

Comment: Если укажете в чём именно вы выводите, это может помочь.

Answer (score 2):

Указать кодировку клиента после соединения. MySQL умеет на лету перекодировать данные, передавая их клиенту и принимая от клиента. Ему только надо знать какая кодировка нужны клиенту, т.е. вашей консольной программе. В консоли mysql вы можете, например, указать что вам нужен utf8 или cp1251, попробуйте и то и другое перед выводом данных из таблицы.

```
MySQL [dbname]> set names utf8;
MySQL [dbname]> select * from mytable;
```

Здесь указывается именно кодировка нужная вашей консоли, а не кодировка данных в таблице. Они могут совпадать или нет, MySQL справится с этим в любом случае.